# Macro shot Q - Why the downvotes?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I found it odd that this question [Were the snowflake photos said to be taken with a compact camera + reversed SLR lens really taken that way?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/45309/were-the-snowflake-photos-said-to-be-taken-with-a-compact-camera-reversed-slr) (which isn't mine) picked up a number of downvotes.  And I've seen similar elsewhere in SE where the person is asking about something and get downvoted if they're in the wrong even if they state plainly that they're unsure.

Is there some SE etiquette I'm missing or is it others misinterpreting the voting system?

Surely the right thing to do is upvote a well written question and then upvote the answer which points out that they've got it wrong, and explains why (which a number of answers to that question do...)

Answer (score 9):

The spirit in which the question is written sounds like rant, while perhaps not really being that. So far what I've seen on this site, rant is not a good writing style here. It may work in writing a blog post, though.

Answer (score 9):

I think the downvotes are for declaring something is a hoax (*"To be honest, I think it's a hoax."*) without real evidence, especially when there is really no indication at all it is a hoax.  Basically, the downvotes are for the arrogant attitude, especially when the OP doesn't seem to know enough behind the technology to make a proper evaluation either way.

Answer (score 4):

The etiquette is much the same as any StackExchange site - if a question shows research effort; is useful and clear, it may be upvoted; If it doesn't fulfill that criteria, it may be downvoted.

It appears from the comments, that there is a perception that no research effort was demonstrated, so I suspect that *may* be why it attracted a couple of downvotes - as well, some of those may have been before the edit acknowledging that alternate firmwares exist, of course.

Comment: There is a whole lot of questions that show no research effort whatsoever, and still get upvoted quite nicely. It must be the other criterias then; useful and clear, well written and generally a "good question".

Comment: @EsaPaulasto, I've seen this fluctuating on the mood, the season, and other random factors. It can be an awfully twitter-length *"The Title Says It All"* question, and somehow, somewhat, someone says *"Interesting question..."* and goes on writing a [Canonical Answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133538/encyclopedia-stack-exchange-and-the-canonical-answer). I do upvote those kind of Q's.